# How I get names into the specific strings

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, dplyr, stringr

I have the following vector:

```
a <- c("teste3/Nova pasta3/texto33.txt", "teste3/texto3.txt", "teste3/Nova pasta3", 
"teste3")
```

In certain cases I have not a vector, but a dataframe

```
structure(list(filename = c("teste1/", "teste1/Nova pasta1/", 
"teste1/Nova pasta1/texto11.txt", "teste1/texto1.txt", "teste1/New Folder/"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I would to get the names that are between slash bar (/*/).
In this case just the name (Nova pasta3) for the vector and the name (Nova pasta1) for the dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: `str_remove_all(str_extract(unlist(a), '/.*/'), '/')`

Comment: `str_extract(unlist(a), '(?<=/).*(?=/)')`

Comment: `sub(".*/(.*)/.*|.*", "\\1", unlist(a))`

Comment: It gives me NA for the other elements in a vector.

Comment: What do you want it to give? the other 3 dont have `/*/` in them

Comment: Sorry, for my fault in the explanation. Elements where not have `/*/` would be removed.

Comment: just drop the `NA` ie `c(na.omit(str_extract(unlist(a), '(?<=/).*(?=/)')))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
str_extract_all(examples, "(?<=/)(.*?)(?=/)")|> unlist()
```

Data:

```
examples <- c("apple", 
       "banana/cherry", 
       "date/elderberry/fig", 
       "grape/honeydew/ice cream/kiwi",
       "lemon/mango/nectarine/orange/pear")
```

Output:

```
[1] "elderberry" "honeydew"   "ice cream"  "mango"      "nectarine" 
[6] "orange"
```